# finding ALL sublist

Tags: prolog

I wrote a predicate to find sublists:

```
sublist([],[]).
sublist([X|T], [X|TS]) :- 
    sublist(T, TS).
sublist([_|T], X) :- 
    sublist(T, X).
```

But it is not correct because it will fail for this:

```
sublist([1,2,20,4,5,6],[1,2,4,20]).
```

How to change this predicate to answer true. For that question without making time complexity much bigger?

Comment: well you even mean subset I guess since you don't preserve order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2015-05-13: Complete rewrite**

It's a bit unclear what you're after here: Your predicate is called `sublist` but judging from your example query, it seems like you're after a `subset`.

Anyway, here are definitions for both predicates:

**`sublist(?L1, +L2)` (order and duplicates matter)**:

```
sublist([], L).
sublist([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :- sublist(Xs, Ys).
sublist(Xs, [_|Ys]) :- sublist(Xs, Ys).
```

**`subset(?L1, +L2)` (order and duplicates do not matter)**:

```
subset([], L).
subset([X|Xs], L) :- member(X, L), subset(Xs, L).
```

Note that these predicates may exist as built in predicates of your prolog implementation. You should not try to redefine those if this is the case.

Comment: Your code would also return `true` for `?- subset([1,2],[1,1]).`, which would probably be incorrect.

Comment: yup, you'd have to go with `select/3` instead of `member/2`.

Comment: @whd, right. I wasn't sure you used a prolog implementation that supported a build in sort predicate.

Comment: @aioobe: consider editing your post to remove/modify your subset predicate, it's not a subset predicate atm.

Comment: @Mog, care to help me out with a counter example? (I'm a bit slow today...)

Comment: @aioobe: `subset([1, 2], X)` creates a infinity of lists containing more and more `1`, `subset([1, 2], [1, 1])` returns true, `subset(X, [1, 2])` seems ok.

Comment: Sorry about the mess guys. Answer rewritten. I hope it's in better shape. Let me know otherwise. (I can't delete it since it's accepted.)